# What is "(something else)" in jol GraphLayout output?

Tags: java, jol

When using jol's GraphLayout class to print the graph of objects referenced from an object instance, some of the output entries say "(something else)" instead of a type and reference path.  For example, consider the following code that prints the graph of a list of 20 random Integer objects:

```
List<Integer> foo = new Random().ints(20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(foo).toPrintable());
```

This code prints:

```
java.util.ArrayList object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                PATH                           VALUE
         d642ecc8         24 java.util.ArrayList                                (object)
         d642ece0         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[0]                212716192
         d642ecf0         56 (something else)    (somewhere else)               (something else)
         d642ed28         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[1]                1503736768
         d642ed38         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[2]                -2099759732
         d642ed48         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[3]                445566433
         d642ed58         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[4]                -1528625708
         d642ed68         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[5]                -555424299
         d642ed78         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[6]                1607595284
         d642ed88         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[7]                763466772
         d642ed98         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[8]                638331919
         d642eda8         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[9]                -1742026575
         d642edb8         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[10]               1920101909
         d642edc8         80 (something else)    (somewhere else)               (something else)
         d642ee18         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[11]               2001035318
         d642ee28         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[12]               -1920666937
         d642ee38         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[13]               -991335829
         d642ee48         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[14]               -47760298
         d642ee58         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[15]               855824902
         d642ee68        104 [Ljava.lang.Object; .elementData                   [212716192, 1503736768, -2099759732, 445566433, -1528625708, -555424299, 1607595284, 763466772, 638331919, -1742026575, 1920101909, 2001035318, -1920666937, -991335829, -47760298, 855824902, 2137884845, -226328690, 1472718384, 890105604, null, null]
         d642eed0         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[16]               2137884845
         d642eee0         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[17]               -226328690
         d642eef0         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[18]               1472718384
         d642ef00         16 java.lang.Integer   .elementData[19]               890105604
```

Searching for `jol "something else"` on DuckDuckGo and Google did not return any useful hits.

What do the "(something else)" entries represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"(something else)" means just that -- something not part of this object graph.  There may be other (live or garbage) objects there, or just a gap in the heap for some VM-internal reason.

Note that the table of objects in the graph is sorted by address.  The ArrayList's `elementData` array is lazily initialized when the first element is added, and when the tenth element is added to the list, `elementData` is reallocated to make room for more elements.  This creates gaps in the heap area corresponding to the (now-garbage) arrays, and jol prints them as "(something else)" entries.  The code responsible for printing these entries is [GraphLayout line 246](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jol/file/19b3861c0a85/jol-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/info/GraphLayout.java#l246) (at least as of this posting).

jol prints this information about heap gaps to aid in understanding garbage collector behavior.  Some of the later [jol examples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jol/file/tip/jol-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/samples/) demonstrate this, such as the [compaction example](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jol/file/19b3861c0a85/jol-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/samples/JOLSample_22_Compaction.java) which shows how the objects referenced from an ArrayList are initially sparse but are compacted by the garbage collector.

Comment: I like when people self-answer on stuff :) I am not sure "something else" is a good notion though: it seems to trip people over and over again. But, I fail to find a better (short) description.